# How to correctly assign template file in IntelliJ?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea

I inherited an old Zope project, and I am also new to Intellij.

Template files got the file ending .xpt (eXtended PageTemplates)

They contain mostly html, but also tal-tags, which either include syntax like person/getName or even "name python: user.getName()".

Currently, those files show white text on black background.

I want those file endings associated with html/xml whatever, so I get a better overview visually.

BUT I really need to keep the Intellij functions like refactor and find usages and so on working, so Intellij finds methods, which are only called inside those templates.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `File -> Settings -> File types`. There in `Recognized File Types` you can find `XML files` template, then in `Registered Patterns` add your file pattern: `*.xpt`

Comment: Thank you - if I do that, does Intellij still recognize methods inside that now as xml handled file? So both refactor and find usages works? Or does Intellij ignore those function calls from now on, as it thinks that is a xml and no python code?

Comment: @jugmac00, hm.. I don't know for sure, but usually `Refactor` searches occurences in XML files as well.

Comment: I just did it - awesome. And by adding keywords separate for tal, html, css, js I got a perfect overview over my template files.

Comment: Good for you. I would appreciate if you'd mark my answer as correct one :)

Comment: Just subscribed here :-) I found one downside of this solution, though. There is absolutely no error/syntax checking now. Is there any chance to activate some kind of checking for correct tags/syntax like for xml/html? Maybe it would have been better to assign xpt to xml or html, get the syntax checking, but some error reports, which are none.

Comment: Nope, never tried to create pattern by myself. You can try to search something [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/new-file-type.html). But I assumed that you associated your `.xpt` file type with `XML` format. It has built in syntax check